# Git for Windows - issue with credential manager

Tags: git, git-for-windows, git-credential-manager

I installed the `Git-2.34.0-64-bit.exe` from [Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/) and picked most of the default options.  The install said that it was going to use the "git-credential-manager-core" which seems to be the newest incarnation of this.

Having completed the install and reboot, when I navigate to a directory with a GIT repo and I type `git status` from the cmd line, it works fine.

But when I type `git fetch` it says:

> git: `credential-manager` is not a git command.  Most similar command is `credential-manager-core`

So, why isn't it using the core version of the credential manager, or rather, what do I need to do to make it use that?

Thanks

Answer (score 15):

> git credential-manager-core configure

Just needed to execute this, then it worked